# label rearrangement

Tags: java, swing

How can I rearrange these labels in order to get a different result?
This is the code:

```
lbl1.setText(" File 1: " + File1.getName());

lbl2.setText(" File 2: " + File2.getName());

lbl3.setText(" Union: File 3 ");
```

The output right now is:

File 1: first.txt

File 2 : second.txt

Union : File 3

What I'd like to get is just one line:

**Union : File 3 (first.txt+second.txt)**

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understand the problem well enough.  If you mean to combine filenamesin the format that you've written:

```
lbl3.setText(" Union: File 3 (" + File1.getName() + "+" + File2.getName() + ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

Neil is right !....

```
lbl3.setText(" Union: File 3 (" + File1.getName() + "+" + File2.getName() + ")");
```

will work for you.